# UnityプロジェクトのGit管理において .meta ファイルの差分が消えない

Tags: unity3d, git, sourcetree

#### 前提・実現したいこと

UnityプロジェクトをGitHubで管理しております。
メンバーの一人がソースツリーをインストールし直し、ブランチの最新をプルしたところ、多くの .meta ファイル, 一部のプラグインファイルに差分が出続けてしまいます。
差分を破棄して、ブランチの最新をプルし、その後 Unity を起動しても同じ内容の差分が出続けます。
このような差分が出るのはそのメンバーのみで他のメンバーには異常はありません。
お知恵お貸し頂けると大変助かります。よろしくお願いいたします。

#### 使用しているツール

- Unity
- GitHub
- Git
- GitLFS
- SourceTree
- Firebase
- Windows10

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

下記の画像のように `.png.meta` が大量に出ます。
差分の内容は全て
`buildTarget: DefaultTexturePlatform` が追加されるという内容になります。
全ての画像ファイルで差分が発生しているわけではありません。大量にある画像ファイルの中で　`buildTarget: DefaultTexturePlatform` が存在していなかったファイルにのみこの差分が出ているようです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
また、 Firebaseの `Firebase/Plugins/link.xml` が追加される症状も発生しております。

#### 試したこと

- ソースツリーのインストールし直し
- プロジェクトのクローンし直し
- Unityバージョンの確認
- .gitignore, .gitconfig, .gitattribute の確認
- .metaファイルのコミット忘れがないことの確認

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

- Unity2019.4.2f1
- Git バージョン 2.28.0/LibGit21sharp 0.26.1 + git-lfs v2.11.0
- SourceTree Version 3.4.1.0
- Firebase for Unity 7.10

Answer (score 1):

UnityのBuildTargetの指定が違っていたようです。
BuildTargetを適切なものに変更したら直りました。